# Unable to apply URL rewrite successfully

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

In-spite of going through all the resources about rewriting URL, I am not able to successfully apply the same to my site.

The URl is `www.mysite.com/Client/?clientname=name`

I want it to be `www.mysite.com/Client/name`

Client is another directory inside the root directory

Please help.

Comment: Can you not show us what you've tried already?

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?clientname=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?clientname=$1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could do with a RewriteCond in there so it checks if it's matching the URL you want. And then you'd want to make that the last (L) RewriteRule once it matches:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Client/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?clientname=$1 [L]
```

Comment: should I put .htaccess file in the root directory or Client directory?